# how to mount windows directory to a windows container

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows

I am trying to mount a windows directory inside a windows docker container that runs with image microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0

I tried below commands

```
docker run -it microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 -v dotnetcore:c:\dotnet
docker run -it microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 -v dotnetcore:c:
docker run -it microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 -v dotnetcore:c:\\
docker run -it microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 -v dotnetcore
docker run -d microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 -v dotnetcore:c:\\dotnet
```

All the above commands threw the error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: container 66e8c16cdf607c9e7ecb049963c602d22c9850f331e3d08c3acc557db4d40814 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) extra info: {"CommandLine":"-v dotnetcore:c:\\dotnet","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\","Environment":{"ASPNETCORE_PKG_VERSION":"2.0.8","ASPNETCORE_URLS":"http://+:80","DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER":"true","DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_SHA":"5cae6f4c577182e7d84d991b9d20162c1a76ce17f65b7b52a7e6df8d98ec389e03626f61969eaed4f23a5f6c96a3ab188e71a0b94cc58f86e485ac9296c4af64","DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_URL":"https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.200/dotnet-sdk-2.1.200-win-x64.zip","DOTNET_SDK_VERSION":"2.1.200","DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER":"true","NODE_DOWNLOAD_SHA":"3d3d72c5c93a50d5a19f65f0de196b5237792a99b89fac2b61e62da4f566c842","NODE_VERSION":"6.13.0","NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE":"skip","RestoreUseSkipNonexistentTargets":"false"},"EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[30,131]}.
```

Any help to resolve this will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `-v` parameter before image name

Comment: Thanks, Tried this 

docker run -v dotnetcore:c:\dotnete -it microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0

This seems to mount the volume. But volume is empty, I cannot see the files in host inside the container. How to mount the volume correctly?

Comment: C:\dotnete>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0A24-39A6

 Directory of C:\dotnete

06/22/2018  12:27 AM    <DIR>          .
06/22/2018  12:27 AM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  166,798,966,784 bytes free

Comment: You need to specify directory on a host instead of volume name, so it shall be `-v c:\tmp:c:\dotnete`